# DevOps .NET 6 Library AutoVersion using Major/Minor from csproj but auto-generate patch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am currently using DevOps pipeline. Our project file versions start with 6.1.x but I have to manually increment the patch version so that it appears as an update within the 'Manage NuGet packages for Solution' after a Pull Request.

I'm hoping that there is a way to use the same Major and Minor version from the csproj file (6.1) but then auto-generate the patch version.

I've tried various tweaks using the guide below but to no avail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines

CSPROJ File

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
        <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
        <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
        <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <PackageId>MyProject.Libraries.Azure</PackageId>
        <Version>6.1.3</Version>
        <Authors>Me</Authors>
        <Company>MyCompany</Company>
        <Product>MyProject.Libraries.Azure</Product>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <NoWarn>1701;1702;NU1701;</NoWarn>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <WarningsAsErrors>NU1605</WarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.18.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

YAML

```
trigger:
- main
- feature/*
- bugfix/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Generate Package
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    arguments: '-c Release -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope it could be helpful to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic package versioning feature of `DotNetCoreCli@2`task doesn't support appending patch version to `PackageVersion`, but overwrites its value by `/p:PacakageVersion` like `/p:PackageVersion=2023.10.12`. See the introduction below on [DotNetCoreCLI@2 - .NET Core v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) .

> versioningScheme - Automatic package versioning
>
> string. Required when command = pack. Allowed values: off, byPrereleaseNumber (Use the date and time), byEnvVar (Use an environment variable), byBuildNumber (Use the build number). Default value: off.
>
> This task cannot be used with included referenced projects. If you choose Use the date and time, this will generate a [SemVer](http://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html)-compliant version formatted as X.Y.Z-ci-datetime where you choose X, Y, and Z.
>
> If you choose Use an environment variable, you must select an environment variable and ensure it contains the version number you want to use.
>
> If you choose Use the build number, this will use the build number to version your package. Note: Under Options, set the build number format to $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

Instead of automatically generating patch version, would you consider specifying `VersionPrefix` not `Version` in the project file and generating `version-suffix` in pipeline as introduced in [dotnet pack command - .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack)? The package version would be `$(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionSuffix)`

Kindly also note that the `arguments` input currently only accepts arguments for `build`, `publish`, `run`, `test`, and `custom`. If you would like to add arguments for a command not listed, use `custom`.

Here is a sample for your reference.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <PackageId>MyProject.Libraries.Azure</PackageId>
      <VersionPrefix>6.1.3</VersionPrefix>
      <Authors>Me</Authors>
      <Company>MyCompany</Company>
      <Product>MyProject.Libraries.Azure</Product>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
</Project>
```

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    custom: 'pack'
    arguments: '-c Release -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --version-suffix $(Build.BuildId)'
```

In case defining/replacing the value of Package Version that includes major, minor or patch versions is not an option for you, you might try and use [Replace Tokens marketplace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to modify the `.csproj` file before packing.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <Version>6.1.#{Build.BuildId}#</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
…    
</Project>
```

```
- task: replacetokens@5
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/*.csproj'
    encoding: 'auto'
    tokenPattern: 'default'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
    enableTransforms: false
    enableRecursion: false
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
```

[image]

Hope the information would be helpful.